# [Linq-To-Sql]How to return two values of different datatypes?

Tags: linq-to-sql, string, int, iqueryable

Here is my repository method which returns `UserId` ,

```
public IQueryable<int> getLoginStatus(string emailId, string password)
{
    return (from r in taxidb.Registrations
           where (r.EmailId == emailId && r.Password == password)
           select r.UserId);
}
```

How to return `UserName` which is a string along with `UserId`... Any suggestion?

**EDIT:**

I tried this it is working but how to get whether the query result contains records or not,

```
    public RegistrationBO getLoginStatus(string emailId, string password)
    {
        return (from r in taxidb.Registrations
                where (r.EmailId == emailId && r.Password == password)
                select new RegistrationBO()
                {
                    UserId = r.UserId,
                    UserName = r.UserName
                }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a class to contain the result then use this:

```
return (from r in taxidb.Registrations
       where (r.EmailId == emailId && r.Password == password)
       select new SomeClass { r.UserId, r.UserName });
```

Seems pointless though... SLaks is right that you can just return the user:

```
return (from r in taxidb.Registrations
       where (r.EmailId == emailId && r.Password == password)
       select r);
```

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: If there are no matching rows then FirstOrDefault returns `null`.

Comment: should i use `RegistrationBO` or `IQueryable<RegistrationBO>`... Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: @Pandiya: The main difference is that the first returns only a single object, the second can return many objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the entire User objects, by change the `select` clause to `select r` and changing the return type to `IQueryable<User>`.

Comment: +1: I think this is a sensible suggestion. Why did it get a downvote?

Comment: If there are no results, it will return `null`.

Comment: @slaks `RegistrationBO` or `IQueryable<RegistrationBO>` what is the difference between the two? What should i use?